# Get source line of a struct definition in GDB python script?

Tags: gdb, gdb-python

There is `gdb.lookup_type("SomeType")` in GDB python API as listed blow, but I cannot find a way to get the source file and line number where the type is defined, much like what the GDB command `info types ^SomeType$` does. Is it possible via GDB python API without invoking into the `info types` command?

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Types-In-Python.html#Types-In-Python

Comment: Try `gdb.lookup_static_symbol("SomeType")`, you should get a [gdb.Symbol](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Symbols-In-Python.html) of the type, with `symtab` and `line` fields.

Comment: @ssbssa `gdb.lookup_static_symbol("SomeType")` seems working, thanks.